# .gitconfig aliases work in one enlistment but not in another

Tags: git

I have the exact same .gitconfig file in two different enlistments. They only have 3 aliases defined. The .gitconfig is applied in one enlistment but not in the other and I can't for the life of me figure out why git isn't loading it. `git config -l` shows the aliases in the repo where it works but not in the repo where it is broken.

How do I troubleshoot this? The files are identical and have identical permissions.
This is on Ubuntu 20.04, git 2.17.1.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "enlistment", but `git config --edit --global` will open your editor on your global `.gitconfig` file and you can thereby see its contents. (Note that the *local* configuration for each Git repository is in `.git/config`, not your personal `.gitconfig`; your personal `.gitconfig` lives in a directory defined by your OS and Git installation.)

Comment: I'm talking about my local working directory (borrowing terminology from other source control systems). Both repos have a .gitconfig file committed in their root directory with these aliases and they work in one but not the other. They don't exist in .git/config or ~/.gitconfig.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally discovered that one repo had a `git config include.path` applied and the other did not. By adding the include to the second repo it fixed the issue.

This is for security purposes and is covered [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes).